# why preview showing different ui and real screen different in constrainlayout

Tags: android, android-studio, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I am developing new android app but when I am trying to implement constrainlayout in preview window it is showing different but in real device showing different

below my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#451C80"
    tools:context=".SetPasswordFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/getStarted"
        style="@style/password"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/getStarted"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.366"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/username"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="223dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:text="@string/create_user"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="544dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/username" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below preview ui in android studio[image: previewui]

and below ui in real device
[image: realdeviceui]

I want to exactly where I am making something wrong what I have to do in order adjust constraints correctly so that I can show exact the same preview window ui in real device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a Bottom margin = 544dp in the textInputLayout,

you should'n use a very larg margins in layouts
you can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#451C80"
    tools:context=".SetPasswordFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/getStarted"
        style="@style/password"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/getStarted"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.366"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/username"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="223dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:text="@string/create_user"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/username" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```